# How to use sklearn pickle object created in first request across all other requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful, urllib3

I have the following use case In my project- Python.
We have a prediction system in place for every user request through API (We are using IIS, need to look at flask capabilities).

The size of a pickle file is huge, like 700MB, I don't want to load it for every request (since it is consuming more RAM for every request).

Can we load the pickle file into flask cache and use it for all the requests? 
  (or) 
Can we share the data among all the requests, so that we don't need to load it again and again?

Please help with the sample implementation of sharing pickle data across all the requests

Answer (score 1):

You can try using something like [Flask-Cache](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/), and do a function like this:

```
@cache.cached(timeout=None)
def get_pickle_object():
    return your_pickle_object
```

This way the pickle object will only be imported the first time this function is called and afterward it will be dumped from cache.

You can also call this once during app initialization so that it is already loaded for the first request.

Then every time you need the object, use `get_pickle_object()` instead of the object itself.

Comment: We opted FastCGI service (One long running process for all requests) in Microsoft IIS server. Also implemented singleton design pattern to create pickle object only once.